# wordpress registration email

Tags: wordpress, email

I am using wp_mail along with the plugin WP Mail SMTP, and the filter wpmu_signup_user_notification to send notification email to new users. The problem is some users are getting the emails and others are not getting the emails. The issue is not restricted to a specific domains: for example some gmail users are getting the notifications and others are not.
If anyone knows what might be causing this, I'll appreciate any help.

Thank you

Comment: Go to https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=wordpress+registration+email+not+sending link and read support post of wordpress.

Comment: I already did that. Most of what I found are issues where messages are not sent at all.